# PdfBox - change font of text in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdfbox

Is it possible to change text fonts in existed PDF through PdfBox? If yes how to do that? I have problems with some special fonts in PDF and I want to change them to font that is widely supported.
Thanks

Comment: First of all you have to make sure that the source document provides the correct information on the encoding used for text written in that font and that the font can be easily identified. Furthermore the original and the replacement fonts have to have essentially identical font metrics (especially character widths). If that is taken care of, it is possible.

Comment: @mkl how is it possible?

Comment: @RiyafaAbdulHameed Please share a representative sample document for demonstration purposes.